# Why do I have to use volumes instruction in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My local folder looks like so:

```
docker-compose.yml
\nginx-proxy
    \code
        index.html
    nginx.conf
    Dockerfile
```

`index.html` contains plain html code. `nginx.conf` contains this simple configuration:

```
worker_processes 1;
events {
    worker_connections   1024;
}
http {
    sendfile on;
    server {
        listent 80;
        root /code;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

`Dockerfile` contains these instructions:

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./code /code
```

And finally `docker-compose` contains these instructions:

```
nginx:
    build: ./nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
        - "8181:80"
```

When I run `docker-compose up` and go to `localhost:8181` for some reason I see a welcoming nginx page (not my index.html), if, however, I slightly change docker-compose.yml:

```
nginx:
    build: ./nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
        - "8181:80"
    volumes:
        - ./nginx-proxy/code:/code
        - ./nginx-proxy/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

So, my question is why do I have to specify this `volumes` instructions? I wish I could instead use my Dockerfile with COPY instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you will not need them, until you for example want to change code on the host and see the changes on the docker container.

Your setup looks good, all you need is defining your build context like

build:
  context: ./nginx-proxy

Other then that your COPY statements will copy the contents right like you expecting during build time , so there is no need to use volumes during runtime for this ( except the sync case as outlined at the top )

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean that the whole problem is in this `context` key word? If I add it and remove volumes, will it work in the same manner as without context and with volumes?

Comment: Right, that should be the case. Conceptually you did/think just right

Comment: Thanks! I will check it in a minute!

Comment: I've just checked it. In this case I get this error message when I run `docker-compose up`: "build path /home/jacobian/Projects/context:.nginx-proxy either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL". What I did is just changed "build: ./nginx-proxy" to "build: context:./nginx-proxy" and removed volumes part.

Comment: Probably, the whole problem is in formatting? Sould I add a new line after `build:` statement?

Comment: I did it. To make it work I had to use two additional key words in docker-compose.yml - "version" and "services".

Comment: It would be great, if you could look at another my question, devoted to docker - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41666793/hello-world-with-official-nginx-and-php-docker-images-howto . Thanks in advance!